# How to get rid of "echo" in my PHP code

Tags: php, regex

I inherited a big php file that I need to fix.  It contains over 500 echo statements that the previous developer included to debug his code.  I need to find an easy way to wipe out all these echo statements so I don't have all this junk output to the screen.  Sometimes he put the echo on the same line as another piece of code.

One thought I had was to create a function called something like "nullo" that does nothing.  Then search and replace the word echo with nullo.  But the "echo" usually doesn't have a parenthesis.  So PHP just gives an error when it encounters a statement like:

nullo 'LABEL: ';

If I need to go through each one and add parenthesis manually, like this:

nullo('LABEL: ');

I might as well just go ahead and delete all 500+ of them instead.
The "echo" is also sometimes on the same line as other necessary code.  So I cannot just // out all those lines.

Here is a sample of some of the code I am dealing with.

```
function sample_func(){
    global $somevar;
    $allnames = "";
    echo 'LABEL: '; foreach($somevar as $var2) foreach($var2 as $pickk){ echo ' -' , $pickk[0]->key , '-' , $pickk[1]->name; $allnames=$allnames.$pickk[1]->name;}
    return $allnames;
}
```

I am not against downloading and installing some fancy IDE/notepad program that could do a smart search and replace.
Any ideas?

Comment: Find in file, and replace, sure you could use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` but in the long run remove them.  `fancy IDE/notepad` == Notepad++ not that fancy though.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix it's a shiny notepad but with the xdebug plugin, it's like a dull IDE (n++4life;)

Comment: @Terminus - shiny perhaps but no where near as rusty as my eclipse Juno... lol

Comment: I guess it's a bit late now, but why not keep the echos and make them only run when you choose to debug? Yes it will be some work but the previous owner probably had a reason to echo out debug messages? Maybe the code is very unstable?

Comment: @Andreas or spend some time and properly set up a test environment with xdebug debugging enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*echo.*\;*[[:blank:]]*/d;s/^[[:blank:]]*echo.*\;//;s/ echo.*\;//' your_file.ext > new_file.ext
```

Edited thanks to comment below :)

The final edit also removes lines which only have echo's making the file much cleaner after the edit.

Comment: This will catch instances of "echo" that appear in the middle of words, such as "prechordal", as @wcarroll points out.

Comment: I believe that @wcarroll 's answer will leave indentation errors if a line begins with an indent and immediately echo.  This answer should solve that issue.

Comment: So I tried this (the sed statement) and it got rid of about 100 of the echo statements.  But there are still 400 or so left.  It did not get rid of simple ones like this:  echo '<br>';

Comment: It looks like user2962623 updated the sed statement in this post since I ran it.  It now contains an extra dot.  I ran that an this time got rid of 379 echo statements.  So that is an improvement.  But not a total fix yet.

Comment: ok I noticed that there is a case where a tab + space + echo line is not caught so I updated it once. More.  Cheers

Comment: Well I am happy to be making progress.  This latest revision got me down to 236 instances of echo.  Here is one line that was left: echo'<br>PARTICIPANTS';   (Maybe because there is no space before the single quote?  Here is another: echo'<br>' , $person->name , ' checking Rules on [' . key($person->rankList) . '] ' , $shift->printShift() . ': ';

Comment: lol didn't think of that case.  Hopefully this last one solves it!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work? It uses a possessive quantifier to reduce the runtime of the regex engine since you're finding over 500 instances... let me know if you'd like any additional clarification or functionality.

```
\becho\b[^;]++;
```

`\b` is a word anchor to make sure that other words like `"prechordal"` aren't matched.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?: `(^|(;))\s*echo\s.*;`

Catches any `echo` that's at the start of a line or preceded by a semicolon, up until the next semicolon. You'd have to backreference with `\2` or `$2` (whichever your editor uses) to replace any leading semicolons that the regex erased.